# How to send miltipart/form-data with aiohttp

Tags: python, multipart, form-data, aiohttp

I need to send payload like this:

```
--XXX
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

John
--XXX
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="age"

12
--XXX--
```

How can i do this?

I am trying to do this, but server returns `{'statusCode': 400, 'message': ['queueType must be a valid enum value', 'query must be a string'], 'error': 'Bad Request'}`

```
async def run(self, query: str, queue_type: str = "generate", preset: str = '1', style: str = "") -> Run:
    url = "https://fusionbrain.ai/api/v1/text2image/run"
    boundary = uuid.uuid4().hex

    writer = aiohttp.MultipartWriter('form-data', boundary=boundary)
    writer.append(io.BytesIO(queue_type.encode("UTF-8")), {"Content-Disposition": 'form-data; name="queueType"'})
    writer.append(io.BytesIO(query.encode("UTF-8")), {"Content-Disposition": 'form-data; name="query"'})
    writer.append(io.BytesIO(preset.encode("UTF-8")), {"Content-Disposition": 'form-data; name="preset"'})
    writer.append(io.BytesIO(style.encode("UTF-8")), {"Content-Disposition": 'form-data; name="style"'})
    extra_headers = {'Content-Type': f"multipart/form-data; boundary={boundary}"}

    async with self._session.post(url, headers=self._headers | extra_headers, data=writer) as response:
        return Run.from_response(await response.json())
```

Comment: This seems that the problem is that you are calling `run(...)` with wrong arguments (or types), not that you are building wrong request

Comment: @sudden_appearance all parameters are str

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem

I took httpx, my code:

```
async def run(self, query: str, queue_type: str = "generate", preset: str = '1', style: str = "") -> Run:
    url = "https://fusionbrain.ai/api/v1/text2image/run"

    request_data = {
        "queueType": (None, queue_type),
        "query": (None, query),
        "preset": (None, preset),
        "style": (None, style)
    }

    response = await self._session.post(url, files=request_data, headers=self._headers)
    return Run.from_response(response.json())
```

Then problem was in Bad Request, i solved it by adding Referer and Origin headers.